# Property 'hibernate.dialect' is unseen (Using Spring Data)

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, dialect

I'm using Spring Data.
I've got "org.hibernate.HibernateException: Connection cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set" on deploy to JBoss7.
But I did set the property (databasePlatform -> org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect) in my app-context.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myproj.persistence.jpa" />

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.myproj.persistence.jpa" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://myhost:port/schema" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="123456" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="quizPersistenceUnit"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="false"/>
                <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>
                <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

This is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="quizPersistenceUnit">
        <class>com.myproj.domain.Quiz</class>
        <class>com.myproj.domain.QuizAnswer</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

However, when I set this property in persistence.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="quizPersistenceUnit">
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
        </properties>
        <class>com.myproj.domain.Quiz</class>
        <class>com.myproj.domain.QuizAnswer</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

everything works great. Of course I don't want to link to DB realization in persistence.xml.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your using the `JpaVendorAdapter` do not specify the persistence unit within the configuration.

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="false"/>
                <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>
                <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Once this is changed you will need to change your component scanning to pick up the Entities.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myproj.persistence.jpa, com.myproj.domain" />
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesn't work. That's realy wierd as I saw the same config in diff tutorials, like this one: http://springtips.blogspot.com/2008/06/spring-entitymanagerfactory-in-jta-and.html. Again: I have the same config with your corrections and I have persistence.xml with persistence unit (without properties and classes)